# Can't access wp-admin after domain change

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, domain-name

I can't access my /wp-admin page after changing domains.

My nameservers and SQL databases still the same, only the domain name has changed. My old domain is pointing to the new one, which causes the new pages to redirect to the home page.

Google has not helped, and this question doesn't seem to have been asked yet, so I'm hoping to hear ideas from the wordpress geniuses out there.

Comment: there is a configuration setting, (remember from when you installed it) where you can set the admin url.  It's either in wp-config.php or in the config table in your db, you can update it.

Comment: if your host has phpmyadmin, or some other db management tool, you need to go into that, go to the wp_options table, and update the values in that table to your new domain name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having that problem, most likely there will be other problems too relating to access to files and other assets for your site after a domain change.

Here's what you can do:

a) dump your existing database to sql (ex. dump.sql ) 
b) using a text editor, open dump.sql from a) and change all instances of **old_domain** to **new_domain** (where **old_domain** stands for the address or name of your old domain, and **new_domain** stands for the address or name of your new domain ) 
c) save dump.sql after changes in b) has been made 
d) delete/purge your database, and use file in c) to recreate your database.

**/wp-admin** will return to you as well as other missing files/references in your wordpress site from your old domain.

Good luck! 
-Glenn

Answer (score 1):

change `siteurl` and `home` entries in your database table `wp_options` according to your new domain, like `http://localhost/public/wordpress` which will point to your home page